# Problema al insertar un registro a la base de datos

Tags: php, pdo, insert

**Este es mi archivo Roles.php**

```
    <?php require_once("../conexion/conexion.php");
    
    class Roles extends Conexion
    {
        
    private $nombre;
    private $conexion;
    
    
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->conexion = new Conexion();
    
        }
    
        public function insertRoles(string $nombre)
        {
            $this->nombre = $nombre;
            $sql = "INSERT INTO roles(nombre) VALUES(?)";
            $insert = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);
            $arrData = array($this->nombre);
            $resInsert = $this->conexion($arrData);
            $idInsert= $this->conexion->lastInsertId();
            return $idInsert;
        }
    
    }
     ?>
```

**Este es rolesControl.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['insertar'])){
    
    include_once '../clases/Roles.php',

    $nombre = htmlspecialchars($_POST['nombre']);

    $objRol = new Roles();

    if($objRol->insertRoles($nombre){
        header("location:../administrador/roles/roles.php");
    }
}
```

Esta es la primera vez que hago un insert de esta forma y resulta que cuando intento insertar no guarda el registro en la base de datos.

Creo que el problema es en el rolesControl.php.

Agradezco si logran solucionar mi problema.

Comment: y que error te sale??

Comment: Justamente ese es el problema, no sale error. Ya lo verifiqué con var_dump()

Comment: pero var_dump no te va a mostrar errores .. para eso se usa try catch...

Comment: Saludos. Por la sentencias que usas el proceso que debes realizar es del siguiente link https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php allí notaras que tu `$resInsert = $this->conexion($arrData);`debe ser `$insert->bind_param("s", $arrData );` (mira en https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php para ver el primer parámetro); para tu `$idInsert= $this->conexion->lastInsertId();` mira en https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.insert-id.php